# Applying a refund to avoid past debt

Tags: united-states, taxes, refund

I am on a tax repayment plan for a previous year, but expect a sizable refund for last year. Can I apply the expected refund towards next years taxes to avoid the IRS automatically applying it to my past debt owed?

Comment: I added a US tag based on the use of phrase “IRS”. If you’re not in the US please comment or edit to say where you are.

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Comment: Even if you could do this, I second @mhoran_psprep's question: why? Presumably you're paying interest on your repayment plan so why would you want the IRS to hold your money and charge you interest for doing it? You'd be much better off knocking out the debt now and owing money in the future interest free.

Comment: Long story, but my ex husband is paying the old  tax debt, so I don't want to give him my refund.

Comment: May want to check out if innocent spouse helps you.... If not you may be out of luck (maybe filing for an extension and then filing the return late may help.... or even just not filing the return until the tax debt is paid)